# Java return type in interface and abstract

Tags: java, interface, abstract, return-type

there, I was taught that interface and abstract class has no implementing/method bodies other than method signatures(name, parameters) and return type, so generally, we write:

```
public void methodName(parameters);
```

However, I am wondering can we write it like:

```
public String methodName(parameters);
```

As it indicates the return type can be in the method when we create interface or abstract class

Comment: No. Unless of course you mean a single type, and not specifying all 3

Comment: @Cruncher, thanks for the reply, I know I cant write all 3:),the "/" means "or", so if I can do it as giving a return type, do I need to change it to  public String methodName(parameters){ return ...};

Comment: How you have it written (`public String methodName(parameters);`) should work. Remember, you don't specify method bodies.

Answer (score 1):

`public String methodName(parameters);`

Should definately work. The following compiles fine.

```
public interface NewInterface {

    public String methodName(String parameter);
}
```